# How to delete migrations file in django using migration command

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, data-migration

I have an app app_blog in django project.I want to delete both migrations file with django migration command.
 blog
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20200126_0741

Answer (score 0):

On your project folder do this:

```
./remove_migrations.sh
```

Then,

If you're using mysql as your db you can simply do this:

```
1. mysql -u root -p (To login to mysql)
2. use database foo; (foo is the name of your db)
3. DELETE FROM django_migrations; (To simply delete all migrations made)
```

Optionally you can specify an app name within your project when deleting myigrations for only that app like this:

```
3. DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = app_blog
```

After deleting the migrations now do this in your terminal where your project resides.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Then try running your local server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Or share for someone to use it using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 (8080 is the port to use)
```